# Compilation error when overloding the Function.prototype

Tags: typescript

I have following methods in a common.js file.  I get a compilation error on the first line when i include the "common.js" file into a typescript file.

How should I solve this ?

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    ///<summary>
    ///Create a new method if it not ready exists
    ///</summary>
    if (!this.prototype[name]) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
        return this;
    }
};

String.method('trim', function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s|\s+$/g, '');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

Just move the common.js file to a common.ts file.  Then add the following code before the line which extends the 'prototype'

```
interface Function {
   method(name: string, func: Function): any;
}
```